# Migrate historic data from GA to FA after January 2020 (For Apps)?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

As we all know, google is going to sunset the old google analytics SDK from **October 2019**, and focusing on firebase analytics.

I recently received this email from google:

[image]

After reading it my understanding is that, we won't be able to access our Google analytics mobile app property from `October 2019` onward and historic data will also be removed from the google servers from 31 January 2020.

Then what about the **historic data** in that property?

Even though we link FA with BigQuery, are we going to get our old data (data before Jan 2020)? Or is there any way to migrate our historic data from Google Analytics to FireBase analytics?

Comment: Just wondering if all your data is in BigQuery why do u think you won't have access?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the link to the quote you are using so that we know its source.   I sent an email off to the team I dont think anyone besides them is going to be able to anwser your questions.

Comment: @DaImTo - we received an email saying this from google. I just can post here a link of that image.[google's message](https://www.simoahava.com/images/2018/12/google-analytics-for-mobile-sunset.jpg)

Comment: @TamirKlein - As FA will start collecting the data from October 19 and all your past data from GA server will be removed from January 2020, Then what about the GA's past data (2-3 yrs old data). BigQuery is not going to save your whole data or past data, right?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to manually move your historical GA data into BigQuery (or some 3rd party tool), and then set up some kind of join to compare newly-collected data (via Firebase) to that historical dataset. Firebase can only view the data that it collects, from the point of integration forward - it doesn't know anything about any data that was collected by another system/product.

Comment: I mean, it makes sense what you are saying, but what is the source of that information? Or is it just your common sense?

Comment: @arekolek 1 - Research: My project is in the same situation, and at the time we were in the midst of migrating data ourselves. 2 - Knowledge: Firebase uses a different data model than legacy Google Analytics, so custom events can't possibly be auto-matched between the two. 3 - Experience: 20+ years working with databases, including product migrations.